# Hive : Cannot copy data from unpartitioned table to partitioned table

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I have an unpartitioned table

```
create table tabUn 
(
    col1 string,
    col2 int
)
```

Lets say it has some data. Next I created a partitioned table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tabPart 
(
    col1 string,
    col2 int
)
PARTITIONED BY (col_date string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/path/to/table';
```

Finally, I tried to copy the data over

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tabPart PARTITION(data_date='2018-10-01')
SELECT 
(
    col1,
    col2,
    '2018-10-01' as col_date
) select * FROM tabUn;
```

but I get the below error

> FAILED: NullPointerException null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement seems to be incorrect.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tabPart PARTITION (data_date='2018-10-01')
SELECT col1,col2,'2018-10-01' as col_date from tabUn;
```